# Pass a js object's attribute into its method

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, this

I have an object, which has a method that uses an attribute. Am I using the attribute correctly?

```
function TestObject(words) {
  this.words = words;

  function alertStuff() {
    console.log(this.words);
  }
}

doItPlease = new TestObject('say something!');
doItPlease.alertStuff();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Properties and variables are distinct in JavaScript.

```
this.alertStuff = function() {
    console.log(this.words);
}
```

The `this` in your example holds reference to the new object. Any parameters/variables in the constructor function have no direct relationship to that object.

---

More idiomatic is to add the function to the common prototype object instead of to each instance.

```
TestObject.prototype.alertStuff = function() {
    console.log(this.words);
}
```

How this works is that when you do `doItPlease.alertStuff()`, the value of `this` in `alertStuff` is automatically set to the `doItPlease` object. Therefore the `alertStuff()` method has  access to that object, and all its properties.

Because all the instances you create from the `TestObject` constructor have the same `TestObject.prototype` object in their prototype chain, there's less memory overhead because they all share that same function.

Comment: Thanks a lot that's much clearer! Is it possible to define a method inside the curly braces of the object definition? I don't want to have one code block defining my object, and another one extending its prototype :)

Comment: @DonnyP: I'm not sure what you mean by the curly braces of the object definition. The only curly braces here define function bodies. And also I'm not sure what you mean by one code block defining the object, and another extending the prototype. Could you explain what you're trying to avoid?

Comment: @DonnyP Yes it is possible. That is called as closure. The functions inside the closure are available only within the scope.